# React code with InitialState and componentDidMount will not run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error i am getting is :

```
SyntaxError:
/home/lucy/Desktop/Lucy/Comms/src/components/imgGallery.js
Unexpected token (12:2) while parsing file:
/home/lucy/Desktop/Lucy/Comms/src/components/imgGallery.js
```

but no matter what i do or remove, the code wont run, the indication of where the error is changes but thats all

my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ImgGallery = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      images: [{"image: "a"}]
    }
  }
  componenDidMount(){

   }

  render (){
   return  (
  <div>
    <div className="imgGallery">

    </div>

   </div>
  )

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the docs, when you use createClass, you have a pojo.  So you must declare the functions using javascript literal notation:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {return ....},
  componenDidMount: function(){},

  render: function() {
   return  (
      <div>
      <div className="imgGallery">

      </div>

     </div>;)
  }
});
```